# How can I mock an ApolloError with code argument in @apollo/client fro testing?

Tags: testing, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo, apollo-server

I'm trying to test how my client handles a specific error I throw in my server like this:

`throw new ApolloError("No applicant found", "APPLICANT_NOT_FOUND");`

My client depends on the `extensions.code` part of result to handle the error. But since `ApolloError` from the package `@apollo/client` apparently doesn't work the same as the one in the server I cannot mock an error accordingly.

This is my mock so far:

```js
export const getApplicantNotFound: Mock = {
  request: {
    query: GET_APPLICANT,
    variables: { codigo: "1234509876" },
  },
  result: {
//on this line typescript says: expected 1 argument but got 2
    errors: [new ApolloError(
      "No applicant found with code 123450987",
      "APPLICANT_NOT_FOUND"
    )],
  },
};
```

Do I need to install the `apollo-server` package to use the `ApolloError` that has `extensions.code` in my client tests? Or is there some way to mock this error in the client?

Answer (score 3):

Digging through `@apollo/client` and `graphql` source code I found that the mock expects an array of  `GraphQLError` which has a constructor like this:

```js
  constructor(
    message: string,
    nodes?: $ReadOnlyArray<ASTNode> | ASTNode | void | null,
    source?: ?Source,
    positions?: ?$ReadOnlyArray<number>,
    path?: ?$ReadOnlyArray<string | number>,
    originalError?: ?(Error & { +extensions?: mixed, ... }),
    extensions?: ?{ [key: string]: mixed, ... },
  )
```

So I wrote the mock with a `GraphQLError` with only `message` and `extensions` like this:

```js
export const getApplicantNotFound: Mock = {
  request: {
    query: GET_APPLICANT,
    variables: { codigo: "1234509876" },
  },
  result: {
    errors: [
      new GraphQLError(
        "No applicant found with code 123450987",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        { code: "APPLICANT_NOT_FOUND" }
      ),
    ],
  },
};
```